# Data structure that will hold a set of integers from 0-127 in the most economical way

Tags: c, data-structures, set

I'm working on an interactive "pocket computer" for performing actions on groups.

One of requirements of the project is to define a "set" type that holds a set of integers from the closed domain [127 ... 0]. The data structure must be economical in terms of the amount of memory required, so for example an array of 128 bytes is not economical.

Comment: how many integers are active at the same time? is it up to 128? If it is more than 16, go for bitmask solution. Is this data structure  constant or it changes in runtime?

Comment: Use one bit for each integer. So a 16 byte array.

Comment: Know that if you try to use an "economical" way to store the values, rather than plain `unsigned char`, then you will have to write a *lot* more code to handle it. A lot more code means a lot more points of errors, more documentation, more effort to work with and maintain the code, and longer time to write. So you can pick either code efficiency (and simplicity), or memory efficiency, but not both. While memory efficiency (your choice) can sometimes be right, you have to add in all the downsides in your work-time equation.

Comment: With the above said, the common way to solve it is to treat values as elements in an array, so you have indexes from `0` to `127` (if you want 128 different values). Store as an array of 112 bytes (again with 128 7-bit values), and create function which can take an index to calculate the underlying array and bit offsets  needed for access to the values, and use bit-manipulation to set and get the bits and form values.

Comment: The amount of memory required to represent **any** set of integers from 0 to 127 is 128 bits. If the amount of memory is allowed to vary depending on the set being represented, then how much memory will be used depends on the data. In that case, answering the question requires having some model of the data. For example, if most of the sets are, say, six or fewer integers, then one solution could be to use 45 bits in most cases—three for a count (0-6) followed by six fields of seven bits for the integers—and 131 in others (7 in the count field followed by a 128-bit mask)…

Comment: … That would have a lower number of bits on average when the portion of sets that have six or fewer integers is high. So, you should clarify the question about whether you want the minimum fixed-size solution or you want a varying-size solution and, if the latter, what is known about the probability distribution of the sets.

Comment: if the maximum value N is known then you can use [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)

Comment: @Yead: The question is tagged C, not C++, so `std::bitset` is not a solution. And comments and answers have already mentioned using a bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Applying basic computer science, then create a bit field.

```
#define MAX_VAL 128

uint8_t bit_field [MAX_VAL / 8];
```

And then access it with the bitwise-operators:

```
void set_bit (size_t n, bool set)
{
  if(set)
  {
    bit_field [n/8] |= 1u << (n % 8);
  }
  else
  {
    bit_field [n/8] &= (uint8_t)~(1u << (n % 8));
  }
}
```

This is a memory above speed optimization.

Comment: Consider adding 'get_bit()' as well